# Error "The passwords provided for the Sugar database user do not match. Please re-enter the same passwords in the password fields"

Tags: mysql, sugarcrm

When tried to install the sugarcrm with mysql database.
It is showing an error

> The passwords provided for the Sugar database user do not match.
>   Please re-enter the same passwords in the password fields

But the entered passwords for both fields: "Password" and "Re-enter password" are same.
I have tried it many times but the error still persist. So please help to connect sugarcrm with mysql.

Answer (score 5):

I assume you are asking about how to have the Sugar installer create a new DB user for you, and are getting this error.

This is a known bug, and yet Sugar has not fixed it.

You can patch the file responsible yourself, OR you can use a known db user (i.e. root or other) and change the user later (in the config.php file), OR create a new user in the db first, then use that (rather than having Sugar create the user).

per http://forums.sugarcrm.com/f115/new-installation-cant-use-option-define-user-create-database-screen-78786/#post281399, there is an extra hidden INPUT in install/dbConfig_a.php that you should remove if you wish to patch the file yourself.

In version 6.5.15, this is line 198.

Based on the forum post linked above, this issue has persisted since 6.4.5 or earlier.

Comment: Sorry, i got a error after the patch of the file. 
"The provided database host, username, and/or password is invalid, and a connection to the database could not be established. Please enter a valid host, username and password "

please help, if you know how to solve this.